# Use one value (in controller) from returned row from model

Tags: codeigniter

I have a function in the model the gets the row of a certain user: fname,lname, etc.

And in the controller I want to only use the fname and save it to session. How will I achieve that? So far I have this

```
$info = $this->User_model->getUserInfo($id);
$userinfo = array(
   'name' => $info->fname //gives me a array to string conversion error
);
$this->session->set_userdata($userinfo);
```

In the model

```
return $query->result_array();
```

I can just get the name by `return $query->row('fname');` but I want to reuse the function that gets the row to be efficient.

I understand the error. But I just don't know how to get around it.

Comment: $this->session->set_userdata('name',$info->fname);

Comment: what are you returning from model row() or row_array() ?

Comment: return $query->result_array();

Comment: @iamDevlin use `return $query->row_array();` instead of `return $query->result_array();`. it will give only one row not more then.

Comment: But there problem will still be there. How will I access a single data in the array in controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in model try this

```
return $query->row_array();
```

and in controller

```
 $info = $this->User_model->getUserInfo($id);
 $userinfo = array(
 'name' => $info['fname']
 );
 $this->session->set_userdata($userinfo);
```

Comment: Do you know any documentation regarding the differences of `row_array` and `result_array` and the others? EDIT: Found them. Thanks, by the way.

Comment: when we want only single record we use row_array()  for result as array & row() for result  as object, and we want more than one record then we use result_array() for  array or result() for as object